# Extract dynamically generated value present in URL before the request is submitted in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

At some point of time, the following URL occurs in jMeter as the request-

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&client_id=${clientid}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fteams.microsoft.com%2Fgo&state=**eyJpZCI6IjNjNzFiODJhLTczMTEtNDkyMS1iM2ViLTY4Mzg5ZjYyOTMzNCIsInRzIjoxNjgyNDE2Njg4LCJtZXRob2QiOiJyZWRpcmVjdEludGVyYWN0aW9uIn0%3D**&nonce=3e7805fe-d2f7-4b25-a3ab-66308a5412be&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS&x-client-Ver=1.3.4&client-request-id=45ca2207-5900-4e38-b933-ebab1668ded8&response_mode=fragment](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&client_id=$%7Bclientid%7D&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fteams.microsoft.com%2Fgo&state=**eyJpZCI6IjNjNzFiODJhLTczMTEtNDkyMS1iM2ViLTY4Mzg5ZjYyOTMzNCIsInRzIjoxNjgyNDE2Njg4LCJtZXRob2QiOiJyZWRpcmVjdEludGVyYWN0aW9uIn0%3D**&nonce=3e7805fe-d2f7-4b25-a3ab-66308a5412be&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS&x-client-Ver=1.3.4&client-request-id=45ca2207-5900-4e38-b933-ebab1668ded8&response_mode=fragment)

How do I capture the bold part? so that I save it in a variable, retweak the same HTTP request and pass it through? There are no redirects, I feel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39pwh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4jYu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENylc.png)

I feel this value is generated from the oAuth server (which is dynamic) and occurs in the URL of the in the request to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you're just being [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) so it should be sufficient to extract this `state` from the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) response header using either [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

Take a look at [atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx](https://github.com/aboyfromipanema/jmeter-oauth/blob/main/atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx) example JMeter script to get an idea of how it could be handled.

If my "feeling" is wrong you can generate current timestamp using [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function and encode it to Base64 using [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) function

Comment: 1) I am not being redirected by that request. State variables are created in the URL, http request parameter and in the Source (view source) (all with same value) dynamically and hence extraction is difficult.

2) Thanks, I will take a look at that jmx

3) I cannot generate the State variable and encode it simply because the token it is generated in the decrypted form is coming from Oauth Server which I will never know.

Comment: Token ID I am referring to in point#3 above is the id from oAuth server in the screenshot#2 in question.